# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple, whats wrong

Tags: python, syntax-error, typeerror

New in Python, help.
Why i get this error:
"TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple,"

```
imheight = []
for i in range(0,len(tables)):
    for j in range(0,len(tables)):
      hij = computeHeight(imp[i],imp[j],'Meter')
      imheight[i,j] = hij
      imheight[j,i] = hij
```

Comment: Can you please provide the expected output format? I'm only guessing it in my answer.

Comment: I cringe in terror when i see `z` appended to every name.

Answer (score 5):

This syntax is wrong:

```
imheight[i,j] = hij
imheight[j,i] = hij
```

Perhaps you meant this?

```
imheight[i][j] = hij 
imheight[j][i] = hij
```

But then again, `imheight` is a one-dimensional list, but you're assuming that it's a two-dimensional matrix. It will only work if you first initialize `imheight` correctly:

```
imheight = [[0] * len(tables) for _ in range(len(tables))]
```

Comment: with this i get "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: @ArunknownUnknownz I updated my answer. You're not initializing `imheight` correctly

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary will get you the assignment behavior you desire:

```
imheight = {}
```

*But* if you later need to iterate over it in some order, this won't be as easy as if you'd done it as a proper list of lists, since dictionaries don't maintain order. However, this may work well enough.

Answer (score 0):

Not

```
imheight[i,j] = hij
```

It should be written like this:

```
imheight[i:j] = hij
```

It means the index from i to j.